# How to calculate ionization energy of an atom provided energy of the electron at ground state?

Tags: energy, electrons, hydrogen, ionization-energy

It is given that in ground state the energy of electron in hydrogen atom is $-2.18\times10^{-18}\mathrm{J}$. I'm required to calculate the Ionization Energy in kJ/mol

**Question for reference:**

> At ground state the eng of electron in hydrogen atom is $-2.18\times10^{-18}\mathrm{J}$. Calculate the I.E in KJ/mol

I could not find it in my book and also tried googling. None of these worked.

It is not a homework question. It is from a question booklet which have high chance of being asked in the upcoming exams.

Comment: As [Homework](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-chemistry-stack-exchange) is considered literal homework, exams, self-study questions, puzzles, worked examples etc. // There is no need to find solution in books, it is based on elementary knowledge that IS in the books and on many internet places. You do know how to multiply one number by another.

Comment: I was confused because 1312.0 is the Ionisation Energy of Hydrogen atom. But it is for one atom. I was asked in terms of kJ/mol which i evaluted to 1312.8 which is pretty close

Comment: I guess you do know the relation of 1 atom and 1 mol of atoms. BTW the ionization energy 13.6 eV is quite well known value.

Comment: Yes. 6.022 10 to the 23 atoms per mole. Some books say 6.023

Comment: 1312.0 is for 1 mole. Sorry for the mistake

Comment: That  I understand. :-).  13.6 eV = 13.6 . 1.602e-19 J.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- **Ionisation energy** : It is the minimum amount of energy required to remove an electron from the neutral gaseous atom.

If the electron is bound to the nucleus then its total energy will be negative. To separate the electron from the nucleus we should supply energy until the total energy of electron just becomes zero.  So by definition the minimum amount of energy required to remove an electron from ground state will be $2.18 \times 10^{-18}J $, which is nothing but the Ionisation energy.